# How to read ISO Speed of an image in Octave?

Tags: matlab, metadata, octave, exif

In MATLAB I used to go:

```
info = imfinfo('image.jpg');
iso = info.DigitalCamera.ISOSpeedRatings;
```

And that's it. Octave has an `imfinfo` function that reads many parameters from the image header, but apparently not the ISO speed. That looks strange to me (why would it read dozens of params and let out ISO speed?).

Is there something I am missing?

Example image is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsyr1ki2cxkpg5n/IMG_1285.JPG?dl=0), shot with a DSLR (as you can see with imfinfo). With MATLAB, I can clearly see that `imfinfo('image.jpg').DigitalCamera.ISOSpeedRatings` is `200`.

Comment: What version of Octave are your running? Octave's `imfinfo` does return a `DigitalCamera` field with the EXIF tags.

Comment: @carandraug Yep, but with no ISOSpeedRatings child. That's what I see at least. 4.0.1

Comment: Can you provide an example image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

<strike>The value you want is under the field `PhotographicSensitivity`. Use:</strike>

```
iso = imfinfo ("image.jpg").DigitalCamera.PhotographicSensitivity;
```

See [Octave bug #47706](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?47706).
Octave only considers tags that follow Exif version 2.3.

## Workaround

Old versions of the Octave image package had a function `readexif` (the function was deprecated in image package version 2.2.0 and removed in version 2.4.0) which may be able to read them. The last version to include that function was [2.2.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/Individual%20Package%20Releases/image-2.2.2.tar.gz/download)

## Discussion

The details you are accessing are the [EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) values on your image file.  Basically, there's a table on your file that maps tags, such as `ExposureTime` or `FNumber`, to their actual values.  However, the tag names are not encoded in the file.  Instead, each tag has an integer value e.g., `ExposureTime` or `FNumber` will appear as 33437 and 33434 respectively.  It's the job of a program/library to map those integer values to the tag name.

The tag you are looking for, `ISOSpeedRatings` is not a valid EXIF tag per the [EXIF specs version 2.3](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf) (the latest specs, released in 2010).  It was renamed to `PhotographicSensitivity`.  If you read the specs under that tag, you will find this note:

> Note that this tag was referred to as “ISOSpeedRatings” in versions of this standard up to Version 2.21.

If you read even more of the specs, you will find the following explanation on Annex G:

> [...] the PhotographicSensitivity tag whose ID was 34855 was previously referred to as ISOSpeedRating, which, in reality, led to confused interpretations of sensitivity that resulted in many recordings that differed from ISO speed as defined under the ISO 12232 standard.

And if you read even more of the specs, you will notice that the meaning of the value with the tag 34855 was slightly changed when its name changed.  This means that it's not only a tag name issue, its meaning is different if your camera follows a different version of the EXIF specs (assuming that your camera recorded it correctly, remember that the reason for the change was that cameras were recording the wrong thing).

I'm not sure what is the right technical answer.  I'm guessing a program should check the recorded ExifVersion (which is the EXIF tag 36864) and change the tag names according to that.

## Edit

Octave uses GraphicsMagick to read images, including its metadata.  GraphicsMagick does not accept the EXIF tag numbers, programs need to query using the tag names.  Octave then has a hardcoded list of tag names but only includes the tags for Exif specs 2.3.  It seems that GraphicsMagick recognizes your file is an older version of Exif and names the tag old way which Octave does not ask for.

Comment: @m_vai I have reported this as an [Octave bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?47706). Could you please upload the problematic image there?

Comment: Thank you. In my case, I can read it with ISOSpeedRatings on MATLAB, but I can't find any PhotographicSensitivity field on Octave. If I understand it correctly, I should find something in both cases, since the tag id is the same.

Comment: I have posted a link to one of the problematic images in my edited question.

Comment: @mvai It's not that clear. Octave then calls GraphicsMagick which calls another librarys (not sure which) to read the exif tags. Would be nice if you could reply on the bug tracker.

Comment: OK, I had missed the last "there" in your first comment. Actually, I can't read ISO speed with any image I have tried. Could you show me an image that works with you (on Octave 4+ possibly), so I can try and see if there's something wrong on my side?

Comment: @mvai all my cameras are older than 2010 and save exif tags 2.1 so I'm affected by the same bug as you. But I got a [test sample for an image with exif version 2.3](http://dev.exiv2.org/projects/exiv2/repository/raw/testdata/trunk/1153/DSC01769.JPG) and still have the same issue. Turns out that this goes deeper and into GraphicsMagick. If you use `gm identify -verbose image-with-exif-23.jpg`, GraphicsMagick still calls the tag "ISO Speed Ratings".

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and can now use readexif from 2.2.2 in image 2.6.1:

- Download Image 2.2.2 as suggested earlier in this thread
- Add the readexif.m from Image 2.2.2 among image 2.6.1
- Reload package `pkg load image`
- Now you can call readexif. To get ISOSpeedRating:

`readexif(JPGPath).Exif_IFD_Pointer.ISOSpeedRatings`